# Code First Automatic Migration with Multiple DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 DbContext on same datatabase with models as below.

```
First DbContext:
  DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
  DbSet<Address> Addresses {get; set;}

Second DbContext:
  DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
  DbSet<Address> Addresses {get; set;}
```

They both have AutoMigrations enabled while sharing "Addresses". I do not want to create an "uber" DbContext including all models for AutoMigrations. After first DbContext has been migrated with "Teachers" and "Addresses" tables created, is it possible to tell AutoMigrations to skip "Addresses" table when migrating second DbContext?